# General understanding about tableview Drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I have a generic question about tableview Draw and reload data, and wanted some insight from this scenario. I have a tableView which get's lazily loaded getting the data parsed from a url. Now the concern is when i select a button and move to another view, I can deselect the object from there, which will remove it from the array. Thus, when I go back to the main view of the tableView, it download's the data again and check's if the object of the further view array is there or not, therefore it set it selected the button.

My concern is, when I go back, my previous selected button is highlighted, and then it does all the computation and de-selects it when the data gets loaded. Is there anyway, I can have the tableView redrawn until the data load's everytime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Looks like that when you are downloading the data & parsing the downloaded data, you are directly passing the modified variable as a source for the tableview. Instead of it, You may store the source for the tableview into another array, which will get updated from source array if it is downloaded & parsed.

Load the tableview using the secondary array.

This is my understanding. If your problem is not resolved , please provide some piece of code for the problem.

BTW, your problem can be resolved using the above solution.

Comment: aah more work to be done.. @iCreative thanks for the idea though, will go forward with that approach.